# How to determine if a distribution is Cauchy?

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, cauchy-distribution

I am making a Cauchy random number generator and I want to make some tests to determine if my code is correct. What are some simple tests I can do to show that the distribution of the generated values is Cauchy?

Comment: This is called a "goodness of fit" test: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=goodness+fit.

Comment: The question is indeed somewhat "dumb" in that this is equivalent to checking whether or not the transform of your output by the Cauchy cdf, $\arctan(x)/\pi+1/2$, is a Uniform sample. There is thus nothing specific to the Cauchy in that test.

Comment: @Xi'an In principle that is true. However, I am testing different methods for generating the numbers where some are from a paper from the 1970's that I am reading and I am not 100% sure if I am implementing the algorithms described in it correctly. So I am looking at ways to verify the correctness of my implementation.

Comment: But if the implementation is incorrect in a way that changes the distribution from Cauchy, once you transform to uniformity in the way Xi'an suggests, you'll see it's not uniform. A test of any continuous fully specified density is equivalent to testing uniformity after the probability integral transform $U=F_X(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Make a qq-plot against the Cauchy distribution. An example with R code:

```r
set.seed(7*11*13)

n <- 10000
cauchy_points <- qcauchy(ppoints(n))
x <- rcauchy(n)

qqplot(cauchy_points, x) # First plot!
qqline(cauchy_points, x)

qqplot(cauchy_points, x, xlim=c(-500, 500), ylim=c(-500, 500))# Second
qqline(cauchy_points, x, xlim=c(-500, 500), ylim=c(-500, 500), 
          probs=c(0.4, 0.6), col="orange")
```

Since you will be testing a random generator, there is no reason to use a small sample size, you should probably use one much higher than in this example. First plot:

[image]

But this plot is totally dominated by the few extremes which a Cauchy distribution will always generate. So we get a better visual test by eliminating some extremes from the plot:

[image]

A formal goodness-of-fit test could be based on the Pearson correlation in this plot, with a simulated p-value.

Comment: For distributions with heavy tails, these plots aren't terribly useful, as you have just discovered.  And using the truncated plots for formal testing obviously loses power.  What's the matter with using the suggestions in the comment thread to the question?  Note, too, that a *big* part of RNG testing focuses on types of dependence among sequential values: it is rare for the output (univariate) distribution not to follow the intended distributional law.